# Laravel api on apache2 ubuntu server 404 not found

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache2, virtualhost

I have a locally created laravel RESTFUL API and I deployed it on my ec2 ubuntu server using git.

I've set it like my main website.. `/var/www/api.myapp.com/public_html/myapp-be` and for its config I have this `/etc/apache2/sites-available/api.myapp.com.conf`.

Almost all blogs and tutorials that I found about deploying laravel on apache2 ubuntu server were almost the same and I've followed them all. However, when I test my API on postman with `https://api.myapp.com/api/somefunctionhere` it says `404 not found, The requested URL was not found on this server. Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at api.myapp.com port 443`. 
But when I test my local api on postman, it works fine, thus, I confirm that nothing is wrong with my laravel.

My config looks like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory /var/www/api.myapp.com/public_html/myapp-be/public/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    
    ServerAdmin developer@myapp.com
    ServerName api.myapp.com
    Redirect permanent / https://api.myapp.com/
    ServerAlias api.myapp.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/api.myapp.com/public_html/myapp-be/public
    
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log combined

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =api.myapp.com [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =api.myapp.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://${SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    <Directory /var/www/api.myapp.com/public_html/myapp-be/public/>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    
    ServerName api.myapp.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/api.myapp.com/public_html/myapp-be/public
</VirtualHost>
```

Is there a spot that I missed here? Obviously I missed a spot but I've been looking for it for almost 3hours already and still wont work.
Any idea guys? Thanks!

**UPDATE: I tried adding /public to the prefix and it worked, I don't even know why it worked -** `https://api.myapp.com/public/api/somefunctionhere`

Comment: Can it be that the `somefunctionhere` is returning the 404.   Have you inspected the **exact** URL being called to the api server?  Have you tried putting that **exact** URL into a browser?  Have you tried that **exact** URL in a curl statement from another server?

Comment: @Zak Yes, I tried putting that exact URL into a browser and still got the same message.

Comment: @Zak I have an update, I added `/public` before the `/api` and it worked

Comment: Only thing I can say is look at your route .. possibly your .htaccess for clues .. I am stumped.